# Breeze: Unable to get property 'propertyRef' of undefined or null reference

Tags: breeze

I have an abstract class and another class:

```
public abstract class AClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class BClass: AClass
    {
        public string OtherName { get; set; }
    }
```

The abstract class have key property, but I received the next error:

> Unhandled exception at line 5007, column 9 in /scripts/breeze.debug.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'propertyRef' of undefined or null reference
>
> Line of error:
>
> breeze.debug.js
>
> var keyNamesOnServer =
>   toArray(odataEntityType.key.propertyRef).map(__pluck("name"));

The entity "BClass" doesn't contain key property, but abstract class AClass contain key property.

Please, help me with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: As of v 1.3.1 Breeze now DOES support inheritance.

Breeze does not yet support inheritance, but it is on our roadmap.  Please vote for this feature on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model) to indicate that you feel that it is important. We take this venue very seriously in prioritizing which features we add next.

Comment: I have updated to the last version of Breeze 1.3.2, but now I have the next error `'deferred' is undefined`.

Comment: In Breeze 1.3.2, I have the next error `Collection navigation properties may NOT be set.` and then the other error `'deferred' is undefined`. Line of error 12074 `breeze.debug.js` `if (state.error) deferred.reject(state.error);`. Please any suggestion.